# Why wont my divs float?

Tags: html, css

Why wont my divs float? Content1 and Content2 should sit side by side. What am I missing? I am sure that it is something simple. i am obviously very early on in this project, so no need to correct all the other crap :).

Here is my css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height:90px;
    background-color: #999999;
}

#container {
    margin-right: 20%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    width: 1000px;
}

#content1 {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}

#content2 {
    width: 405px;
    float: left;
}

#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:90px;
   background-color: #999999;
}
```

Here is my html:

```
<div id="header">
  My Personal Page
</div>

<div id="container">

<div id="Content1">
  <img src="http://localhost:8888/portrait.png" height="400">
</div>

<div id="Content2">
  <img src="http://localhost:8888/portrait.png" height="400">
</div>

</div>

<div id="footer">
  Copyright Information
</div>
```

Comment: Try `float: right;` on `#content2` and remember that IDs are case sensitive (make the CSS and ID of your `div` match)

Comment: Because `Content1` isn't the same as `content1` etc. http://jsfiddle.net/fA5P3/

Comment: Make sure you float one of the elements right using `float: right;' and make sure the names of your id match: `content1` may not be applying to `Content1'

Comment: Haha thanks guys, this is why I should code more often than once a year. All good now, thanks for the quick responses.

Comment: checkout oGeez change `<div id="Content1">` to `<div id="content1">` and `<div id="Content2">` to `<div id="content2">` and they will sit next to each other :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you wrote your `id's` wrong. 
The name of the ID must be excactly the same as the name in your css sheet. In html you have `Content1` with an uppercase **C** while in your css you have `content1` with a lowercase **c**. 
This same scenario you have with `Content2`*(html)* and `content2`*(css)*.

**Your html:** *(Wrong)*

```
<div id="Content1"> && <div id="Content2">
```

**New html:** *(Right)*

```
<div id="content1"> && <div id="content2">
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qqgtQ/)**